# Mocha Unit test : test objectS have id unique

Tags: unit-testing, unique, mocha.js

I'm learning how to do Unit test. I'm doing lot of test but i have got question : Is it good to test my callback.

Explain : I have got a method wich return objects :

```
{
    id: 1
    token: "aa"
    lastname: "Lastname 1"
    firstname: "Firstname 1"
    mail: "user2@yahoo.com"
}
-{
    id: 2
    token: "bb"
    lastname: "Lastname 2"
    firstname: "Firstname 2"
    mail: "user2@yahoo.com"
}
```

And in my unit test i would like to test my id for each object my attributes 'id' is unique. I don't want to have an id :1 twice for example. So i'm wondering if it was something to test and if it is, how can i do that ? I don't find anything with unique attributes id or something like that. And in unit test can we use some lib like lodash ? or should we only use lib for unit test ?

Thanks a lot for your advice and help.
Thanks :D